# Purging commit from GitHub via git rebase prompts me for "More?"?

Tags: windows, git, github

I have a GitHub repo that has a Python script in it, and in that Python script there is some code I committed that accidentally contains some important credentials/secrets:

```
storage_account_name = "some_account"
storage_account_key = "abc123"
```

In that code above, both `storage_account_name` and `storage_account_key` are critical secrets that should not have been committed to source code. But it's too late, I committed and pushed the code to GitHub.

I need to create a local branch, update them to:

```
storage_account_name = "<CHANGEME>"
storage_account_key = "<CHANGEME>"
```

...and then commit and push that to GitHub. But somehow, either before or after that, I need to erase/purge the specific commit (that contained their real values) so that there is no history whatsoever in GitHub that I ever pushed the sensitive credential. This is a security concern: no one should ever be able to look at the repo's commit history and see the version of the file that contained the "abc123" value. How can I accomplish all of this? **Please note**: this is my own private repo but I do plan on sharing it with others in the future.

I Googled how to do this, and it looks like I need to commit and push a change (containing the CHANGEME values), and then afterward, do a **Git Rebase**. So I looked up my commit ID (the one when I accidentally introduced the real values), and I tried doing the rebase:

```
git rebase -i <redacted>^
```

When I do this, the command-line just says: "More?":

[image]

What's going on with that? How can I purge the commit from history (with or without the rebase)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You used `^` for representing "the parent commit", but this symbol happened to be the escape character for command prompt.

You need to quote the whole thing `"b5ac9...7a^"`.